# Can a Snap shot for the SharePoint application server and/or to the SharePoint database server affect the migration process

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, migration, administration, sharepoint-on-prem

I am using a third part tool named share-Gate to migrate our SharePoint on-premises 2013 sites to SharePoint online. Now during the migration process, i am planning to do the following from sharepoint side:-

1. Stop the search service (where i am going to set the full crawl and incremental crawl to run weekly and i chose a day that is different from the day i am planning to do the migration).
2. i have stopped the farm backup schedule task which we perform every day @5 am.

I did the above 2 steps to prevent any issues + to have the best performance for my on-premises sites. 
But today i have this issue in my mind; is that our system admins takes a snap shots for our SharePoint application server and SharePoint database server every day (not sure about the exact time). So my question is, can those snap shots affect our migration process? Or it is safe to do a migration between SharePoint on-premises and SharePoint online while our on-premises servers are being snap shot?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

VM snapshots are not supported with a SharePoint farm. How they take snapshots will highly impact how much of a performance hit you will see on your farm; we cannot tell you what that impact is. It's best that you perform a measurement if you're concerned about it.

But you'll be primarily impacted by the throttling of ingestion of content into SPO anyways, so it's likely not a concern to be performing backups and so forth on-prem.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. now if we eliminate the performance draw backs that a snap shot can cause to the SP on-premises farm,, are there other issues or drawbacks the snapp shots can cause to our migration? for example does the snap shot lock some SharePoint files and items, so they will not get migrated? ..

Comment: You need to speak to the vendor supplying your snapshot software. We cannot answer this without more specifics.